# Is there a way to convert a swf to an .abc file?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex

I'm looking for a way, preferably a command-line utility, to pump out an .abc file for a compiled swf. I've looked into asc.jar, but so far it seems like it can only accept classes, not compiled swfs. Anybody know of a good way to do this?

The end-goal of this process is to use Zwetan's RedTamarin project to run describeType on some specific classes inside a loaded swf, but there are complications with SecurityDomain preventing me from using Loader.loadBytes. If there's another good way to describe classes in the loaded swf via command-line, I'd be interested in that solution as well.

Cheers,

J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you look at a recent abcdump.as there is the options to dump the *.abc file(s)
http://hg.mozilla.org/tamarin-redux/file/ec60d0d30d67/utils/abcdump.as

> Option -a Extract the ABC blocks from
>   the SWF/SWC but do not otherwise display their contents.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish, but [nemo440](http://www.docsultant.com/nemo440/) might be useful.

Comment: Thanks, grapefrukt, but that's not *quite* it. It looks like nemo, as well as swfdump and flasm, just kicks out a human-readable representation of the bytecode, not the actual .abc file. In nemo's listed input formats, it lists .swf (both compressed and uncompressed) AND .abc, but provides the same text dump for both. I'm looking to convert from .swf to .abc, no need to be able to read it :P

Comment: @Jeremy: SWF is just a container format. The ABC is embedded unaltered, as far as I know. Just grab the SWF specs and find how ABC is embedded. Alternatively you can use `swfdump` or `swfutils` from the flex sdk in `/lib/` with `-abc source.swf > out.abc`.

Comment: @back2dos: doesn't look like that's quite right either. The sabc file generated by swfdump is going to be the same as previously mentioned, meant to be human-readable. I'm talking about a legitimate .abc file, as described in these two posts:

http://coderhump.com/archives/104
http://coderhump.com/archives/105

The .abc file he's using can be generated from a class via asc, then loaded into the Tamarin runtime. Take an .abc file created this way and compare it to the text dump from swfdump, nero, or flasm, and you'll see the difference.

Comment: Also, I forgot to reiterate a couple things: First is that I'm hoping to produce the .abc file from a swf, not a class, so it doesn't appear that I can use the asc.jar tool. Second is that I'm attempting to do exactly what the second post describes, and that is to load class definitions at Tamarin's runtime. If there are other ways to do this (besides Loader.loadBytes) I'd be equally interested in other approaches. The .swf-.abc conversion is a middle step that I'm settling for and if it can be avoided I'd be cool with that too.

Answer (score 1):

Use apparat (need scala) from google code, to merge all doAbcDefine in one:

> cd apparat && ./reducer -m true -i file.swc -o merged.swc

Then extract (unzip) library.swf from merged.swc

(hum, question was about swf2abc. I think you can 'reduce' your file.swf directly)

then you can extract (the unique) abc with abcdump from google code maashaack:

> abcdump -a library.swf

then you obtain (an unique) library.abc

Comment: FYI to anyone interested, I have problem running apparat in OS X, but it runs fine in ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Just an update to this question. I needed to extract ABC files from a SWF file and tried different options. The only one that I could get to work in my environment (MacOSX 10.7) was to use the [Furnace](https://github.com/whitequark/furnace-avm2) command line tool.